# Writing Mock RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have code in my Ruby on rails project as follows, to get HTTP response from non rails API

## app/model/rest_api.rb

```
require "uri"
require "net/https"
require "net/http"
require "active_support"
class RestApi
  # the URL for the Twitter Trends endpoint
  @url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/trends.json'

  def self.sampleRes
    uri =  URI.parse( @url)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    response = http.request(request)
    return response
  end
end
```

I have just started learning Ruby on Rails and RSPEC. Can someone please help that how can I write RSpec for HTTP request without actually making request to actual API URL(need some mock)

Answer (score 3):

You can mock out the request part and make expectations about what should be called etc.

```
mock_req = double("http request")
mock_req.should_receive(:request)
Net::HTTP::Get.should_receive(:new).and_return(mock_req)
```

Your code could also be simplified to:

```
open('http://api.twitter.com/1/trends.json').read
```

You aren't doing any error handling, status checking etc. (maybe this is example code?) but, whatever you expect your request to return you should mock/stub out those expectations.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the quick response.
Can you please help me out for writing test cases in ruby's test:unit for the same REST API handling given above in example.